# Для каждой категории показать свои атрибуты в списке товаров на страницах архива/категорий в WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть код, который выводит заданные атрибуты товаров на страницах архива/категорий.

```
/* Show product attributes */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'new_template_loop_product_meta', 20 );

function new_template_loop_product_meta() {
    global $product;

    $attr_list = [
        'Brand'        => 'pa_brand',
        'Country'      => 'pa_country',
        'SKU'          => 'sku',
        'Material'     => 'pa_material',
        'Type'         => 'pa_product_type',
        'Color'        => 'pa_color',
        'Size'         => 'pa_size',
        'Model'        => 'pa_model',
        'Collection'   => 'pa_collection',
        'Mechanism'    => 'pa_mechanism',
        'Magnetic'     => 'pa_magnetic',
        'Side'         => 'pa_side',
        'Load'         => 'pa_load',
        'Availability' => 'pa_availability',
    ];

    if ( ! is_object( $product ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    echo '<div class="pa">';

    foreach ( $attr_list as $attr_title => $attr_name ) {
        show_attribute( $product, $attr_title, $attr_name );
    }

    echo '</div>';
}

/**
 * Show attribute.
 *
 * @param WC_Product $product    Product.
 * @param string     $attr_title Attribute title.
 * @param string     $attr_name  Attribute name.
 */
function show_attribute( $product, $attr_title, $attr_name ) {
    if ( 'sku' === $attr_name ) {
        $attr = (string) $product->get_sku();
    } else {
        $attr = $product->get_attribute( $attr_name );
    }

    if ( '' === $attr ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $attr_title ) . ': </span><span class="pa-right">' . esc_html( $attr ) . '</span><br />';
}
```

Также есть категории товаров, в которых нужно показать только определенные атрибуты из перечисленных в коде.

Например, в списке товаров "Категории А" нужно показать атрибуты `pa_brand, pa_country`.
В списке товаров "Категории В" нужно показать атрибуты `pa_brand, pa_model` и т.д.

Как я понимаю, нужно указать id категории `$cat_id = 197;` и `$cat_ids = $product->get_category_ids();`
И для каждой категории задать свой список атрибутов товара.

Но как все это объединить в один код? Подскажите, как это можно сделать?
Я думаю, что и другим пользователям ответ на этот вопрос пригодится.

Буду рад вашей помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот работающий код:

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'new_template_loop_product_meta', 20 );

/**
 * Show product attributes
 */
function new_template_loop_product_meta() {
    global $product;

    $attrs_by_cats = [
        27 => [ 'pa_brand', 'pa_country', 'pa_color' ],
        28 => [ 'pa_brand', 'pa_model' ],
    ];

    $attr_list = [
        'Brand'        => 'pa_brand',
        'Country'      => 'pa_country',
        'SKU'          => 'sku',
        'Material'     => 'pa_material',
        'Type'         => 'pa_product_type',
        'Color'        => 'pa_color',
        'Size'         => 'pa_size',
        'Model'        => 'pa_model',
        'Collection'   => 'pa_collection',
        'Mechanism'    => 'pa_mechanism',
        'Magnetic'     => 'pa_magnetic',
        'Side'         => 'pa_side',
        'Load'         => 'pa_load',
        'Availability' => 'pa_availability',
    ];

    if ( ! is_object( $product ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    $cats = $product->get_category_ids();

    if ( ! is_array( $cats ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $attrs = [];

    foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
        if ( isset( $attrs_by_cats[ $cat ] ) ) {
            $attrs[] = $attrs_by_cats[ $cat ];
        }
    }

    $allowed_attrs = array_unique( array_merge( [], ...$attrs ) );

    echo '<div class="pa">';

    foreach ( $attr_list as $attr_title => $attr_name ) {
        if ( in_array( $attr_name, $allowed_attrs, true ) ) {
            show_attribute( $product, $attr_title, $attr_name );
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';
}

/**
 * Show attribute.
 *
 * @param WC_Product $product    Product.
 * @param string     $attr_title Attribute title.
 * @param string     $attr_name  Attribute name.
 */
function show_attribute( $product, $attr_title, $attr_name ) {
    if ( 'sku' === $attr_name ) {
        $attr = (string) $product->get_sku();
    } else {
        $attr = $product->get_attribute( $attr_name );
    }

    if ( '' === $attr ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $attr_title ) . ': </span><span class="pa-right">' . esc_html( $attr ) . '</span><br />';
}
```

В массиве `$attrs_by_cats` укажите соответствия id категорий и атрибутов.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Подскажите, в каком виде должны быть категории? Я вставлял ярлыки категорий и их id, также прописывал нужные атрибуты... Они не показываются в списке товаров.

Comment: Там должны быть номера категорий. Или оставьте слаги, но смените в коде на $cat->slug

Comment: Я проверю код чуть позже

Comment: Да, было бы здорово. Просто в качестве теста ставлю корректные значения `    $attrs_by_cats = [
        '197' => [ 'pa_brand', 'sku', 'pa_availability', 'pa_color', 'pa_size' ],
        '203' => [ 'pa_brand', 'sku', 'pa_availability', 'pa_color', 'pa_size' ],
    ];` и ничего не выводится.

Comment: Так в любом случае не могло работать. id целочисленные. Я исправил ошибку в коде и проверил у себя - работает.

Comment: Все отлично работает. Спасибо за помощь! Жаль, что баллы репутации по правилам смогу начислить только через 16 часов ((

Comment: Нет проблем) ответ принят, баллы начислятся автоматичечки позже.